# Edit Reject Reasons list ... no decline for "removed tag"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just reviewed a few questions where the editor just removed a tag.

One was justified, one not and when Rejecting it, I got this list:

[image: Why are you rejecting this edit Dialog]

I rejected it with "causes harm" and described briefly why the tag should stay.

Since there is a `irrelevant tags` entry, shouldn't there be the opposite also? Or maybe the `irrelevant tags` entry could be slightly reformulated to cover both reasons?

Meta Note: I normally do not participate in reviews, I just went in there because I got notified because one of the edited questions was mine.

Comment: I would go to "no improvement" myself.

Comment: The "causes harm" reason does seem to be the best fit. From your description, it seems the edit it is slightly worse than "no improvement", I agree that it would be useful to modify the "irrelevant tags" reason to also cover the deletion of relevant tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can always provide a custom reason with "causes harm," there's no harm in that, you're using it correctly.  I traditionally use that to provide a more descriptive message to the user who suggested the edit, and to the other reviewers (after they have reviewed of course).  The suggested edit in question would probably also fall under the reject reason "no improvement whatsoever" if adding or removing a tag does not improve the fundamental issues with or overall quality of the post.